# How should I set up a private npm registry?

Tags: npm, nexus, artifactory

For a company project, I'd like to set up a private npm registry using Artifactory or Nexus, so packages can be shared with everyone without publishing them on https://registry.npmjs.org/

In maven I would set up a release and a snapshot repo. For resolving I would put them in a group alongside a proxy of maven central.

How does a setup for npm look like? npm's semver is able to differentiate release and prerelease, but I assume that routing them to different registries could be quite a difficult task.

On the other hand one might want to be able to have control over what gets pushed to the "release registry", implementing permissions accordingly. For this you would have to use a "prerelease" and a "release" registy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of how to do this in Nexus Repository if you really need to, I'd suggest setting up:

`npm-release (npm hosted)
npm-prerelease (npm hosted)
npm-all (npm group)`

Make the group include both members (so you can install using one URL), and then in your build script or whatever you are using to publish into Nexus Repository, just use the --registry flag to specify which repository you want to publish in to, something akin to this for a "release":

`npm publish --registry http://localhost:8081/repository/npm-release/`

And this for a "prerelease":

`npm publish --registry http://localhost:8081/repository/npm-prerelease/`

Here are the npm docs for Nexus Repository 3.x if you need some more help: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/npm.html

Comment: An alternative could be GitLab, if you're already using GitLab (FOSS version), it also comes with a free package registry as well: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/

Answer (score 2):

according this link. [How to set up a free private npm registry… for Windows](https://medium.com/@Anderson7301/how-to-set-up-a-free-private-npm-registry-for-windows-f532c6a381ce)

you can use the `Verdaccio`.follow this:

1. Download the ‘Current’ version of [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) .
2. Install Python. Open **Powershell** as an `Admin` and run

   `npm i -g --production windows-build-tools`

   then Run

   `npm i -g node-gyp`.
3. Get the `Python.exe` file path.

   Verify where Python was installed, typically it is stored in the following folder

   > C:\Users\user-name.windows-build-tools\python27

   *copy the path + \python.exe*.
4. Add a new `Environment Variable`.

   open the `File Explorer` and right-click on `Computer` and select `Properties`.

   Select `Advanced system settings` and then select `Environment Variables`.

   If `PYTHON` is not listed under `System Variables` select `New`.

   Add `PYTHON` as the variable name and the `saved path from Step 3` as the variable value -> Select `OK`.

**Installing / Configure Verdaccio**

1. Open up a `command prompt` and run `npm i -g verdaccio`.
2. Verify the install for `Verdaccio` was successful.
3. Open up a `new command prompt` and run `verdaccio` You should see the following output.

[image]

Open up your favorite browser to `localhost:4873`

[image]

more info:

[www.verdaccio.org/docs/en/installation](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/installation)

[www.npmjs.com/package/verdaccio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verdaccio)

I hope is useful.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you would like to have the ability to have a "release" and "snapshot" repository for NPM same as you have now for Maven.

If this is indeed the case then what you can do in Artifactory is to set 2 repositories, one for the "prerelease" and another one for the "release" and aggregate both under one virtual NPM repository. As you mentioned you can have a different set of permissions for each repository and therefore control who can deploy/resolve dependencies and also have the ability to move artifacts from one another.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Hi Ariel, thanks for answering. My question was if that would be a common way/best practise in working with private npm registries. Or would you suggest a different approach?

Comment: Personally, I think you could use one repo, it's not like npmjs.org has two separate repos for prerelease and release. The example I gave was mostly just, if you really want to do it this way (due to some security necessity), here it is.